# Telegram add scraped users from a csv file from a specific line to specific line

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, telegram

Please is somebody who can help to customize bellow code to make it able to add Telegram scraped users from a CSV file from a specific line to a specific line (ie: from line 13 to line 32 of the CSV file). I need it to avoid get account banned by telegram by adding my group users in my channel.

```
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient
from telethon.tl.functions.messages import GetDialogsRequest
from telethon.tl.types import InputPeerEmpty, InputPeerChannel, InputPeerUser
from telethon.errors.rpcerrorlist import PeerFloodError, UserPrivacyRestrictedError
from telethon.tl.functions.channels import InviteToChannelRequest
import sys
import csv
import traceback
import time
import random

api_id = 111111111   #Enter Your 7 Digit Telegram API ID.
api_hash = '0000000000000000000000'   #Enter Yor 32 Character API Hash
phone = '+2000000000'   #Enter Your Mobilr Number With Country Code.
client = TelegramClient(phone, api_id, api_hash)
async def main():
   # Now you can use all client methods listed below, like for example...
   await client.send_message('me', 'Hello !!!!!')


SLEEP_TIME_1 = 300
SLEEP_TIME_2 = 300
with client:
   client.loop.run_until_complete(main())
client.connect()
if not client.is_user_authorized():
   client.send_code_request(phone)
   client.sign_in(phone, input('40779'))

users = []
with open(r"Scrapped.csv", encoding='UTF-8') as f:  #Enter your file name
   rows = csv.reader(f,delimiter=",",lineterminator="\n")
   next(rows, None)
   for row in rows:
       user = {}
       user['username'] = row[0]
       user['id'] = int(row[1])
       user['access_hash'] = int(row[2])
       user['name'] = row[3]
       users.append(user)

chats = []
last_date = None
chunk_size = 200
groups = []

result = client(GetDialogsRequest(
   offset_date=last_date,
   offset_id=0,
   offset_peer=InputPeerEmpty(),
   limit=chunk_size,
   hash=0
))
chats.extend(result.chats)

for chat in chats:
   try:
       if chat.megagroup == True:
           groups.append(chat)
   except:
       continue

print('Choose a group to add members:')
i = 0
for group in groups:
   print(str(i) + '- ' + group.title)
   i += 1

g_index = input("Enter a Number: ")
target_group = groups[int(g_index)]

target_group_entity = InputPeerChannel(target_group.id, target_group.access_hash)

mode = int(input("Enter 1 to add by username or 2 to add by ID: "))

n = 0

for user in users:
   n += 1
   if n % 80 == 0:
       sleep(60)
   try:
       print("Adding {}".format(user['id']))
       if mode == 1:
           if user['username'] == "":
               continue
           user_to_add = client.get_input_entity(user['username'])
       elif mode == 2:
           user_to_add = InputPeerUser(user['id'], user['access_hash'])
       else:
           sys.exit("Invalid Mode Selected. Please Try Again.")
       client(InviteToChannelRequest(target_group_entity, [user_to_add]))
       print("Waiting for 120-180 Seconds...")
       time.sleep(random.randrange(120, 180))
   except PeerFloodError:
       print("Getting Flood Error from telegram. Script is stopping now. Please try again after some time.")
       print("Waiting {} seconds".format(SLEEP_TIME_2))
       time.sleep(SLEEP_TIME_2)
   except UserPrivacyRestrictedError:
       print("The user's privacy settings do not allow you to do this. Skipping.")
       print("Waiting for 30-60 Seconds...")
       time.sleep(random.randrange(30, 60))
   except:
       traceback.print_exc()
       print("Unexpected Error")
       continue
```

Thanks by advance